# Obtain wordpress user role

Tags: php, user-roles

It is possible to obtain the user role in Wordpress from an external PHP application?

I explain myself better:
I am using the OAuth server plugin in my Wordpress site and I have created a script in another PHP site so that it is only possible to access this site if the user is registered in the Wordpress site. Now what I need is to obtain the role of the user that is entering my PHP site, using Curl I have been able to obtain the Id assigned to the user in Wordpress but I need the role to assign privileges in my PHP site. 
Any way to do this? 
How do I get the user's credentials from an external PHP site?

Comment: Note that roles are just collections of capabilities, if you had a capability you were looking for, then that would be significantly easier to answer, and significantly more useful

Comment: As Tom said roles are just capabilities.  Capabilities are stored in the wp user meta table.  So any script that has access to the DB & knows the wp prefix for the site, can connect to the data base, and then query the prefix_usermeta for metavalues with user id and meta key = prefix_capabilties.   The value will ve a serialised array of capabilties.   Unserialise and check for the capability the user should have.  See https://i.imgur.com/MhrbP0r.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the logged in user to get one form from other application only if he/she is Administrator and here is how I checked it. You can check for any role (even new role made through custom user role).

```
<?
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');  //to load from any folder
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
if (in_array("administrator", $user_info->roles)) {
//greet or any other function to call if you want
} else {
die("Login as Admin to continue");
}
// other code below if user passed your role requirement
// otherwise the content will not be shown to him/her.
?>
```

We have to use in_array for checking user roles because you can assign multiple roles to users.

I saved that code in "chkuser.php" and in the beginning of any other php page, I do `<? include "chkuser.php"; ?>` and program will stop there if user was not an Administrator.